# How do I get a button to copy something?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<input value="hello" id="p1" readonly style="width: 100%;">
    <br><p>
        <div class="btn-main">Copy!</div>
```

When visitors press the class "btn-main" I want the input value to be copied to their clipboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: I tried, didn't seem to work.

Comment: https://codepen.io/shaikmaqsood/pen/XmydxJ/

Comment: @sivert If you tried something, post it!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
  }
```

```html
<button id="demo-btn" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('demo-btn').innerHTML)">Copy!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You may use [jQuery clone() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_clone.asp)

**Description :-** The clone() method makes a copy of selected elements, including child nodes, text and attributes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").clone().appendTo("body");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this as well,

```js
document.getElementById("copyBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  target = document.getElementById("p1");
  target.focus()
  target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

```html
<input value="hello" id="p1" style="width: 100%;">
<br>
<p>
  <button id="copyBtn" class="btn-main">Copy!</button>

  <textarea></textarea>
  <p> Press Ctrl + V in the text area to see the copied text</p>
```